# Why is parafluorophenol is more acidic than phenol?

Tags: acid-base, resonance

I have learnt that the +Mesomeric effect (+M effect) of fluorine at para position dominates its -Inductomeric (-I effect) nature. If we see that the acidic strength (with the help of stability of their conjugate anion then in parafluorophenol fluorine) will exert its +M effect at the negative charge of oxygen, then that's why the stability the of parafluorophenoxide ions should be less than normal phenoxide ion. Hence, the acidic strength of the phenol should be greater than parafluorophenol, but the actual acidic strength of parafluorophenol is greater than phenol.  Why is this?

Comment: From the [experimental pKa tables in a fairly authoritative reference](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/), phenol and 4-fluorophenol have indistinguishable acidities (both compounds have pKa 18.0 in DMSO and 9.95 in water). It would be interesting to compare the gas-phase acidities to remove the solvent dependence, but regardless of those last data, it's clear that no hand-waving argument would be sufficient to explain the precise ordering of acidities for these compounds,

Comment: @Nicolau Saker Neto: I think the value of pKa for 4-fluorophenol is a mistake. The referenced article ( J. Org. Chem. 1984, 49, 1424) did not reported a value for this compound. However, it reported the values for 3-fluorophenol and 3-chlorophenol, which are 15.88 and 15.83, respectively (remarkably close). It also reported the value for 4-chlorophenol (16.74). So, I assume the value for 4-fluorophenol should be around that (about 100 times acidic than phenol).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne That is an interesting find, though it's puzzling that the link I gave also reports the pKa in water, compiled by a different author (R. Williams instead of Reich and Bordwell), and yet once again the two compounds are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Nicolau Saker Neto: The values I gave here are from original article. They have some values in water and in gas phase as well. I think the link you sited may have made a mistake. :-)